An example problem of converting a maximum likelihood problem into a restricted maximum likelihood problem
I have a question about this derivation.  What is an example value of the actual matrix $A'$ such that $A'X=0$, $A'A=I$, and $\frac{1}{n}\Sigma((A'Y_{i}-mean(A'Y))^{2}=\frac{1}{(n-1)}\Sigma((Y_{i}-mean(Y))^{2}$, where the last formula comes from the formula for the ML estimate variance of the transformed problem equaling the REML estimate for the variance of the untransformed problem.
Note that $A'$ in the equations above also equals $C$ from this derivation.
Also, does $A'$ equal $K$ from this answer?
